# How Can i set the Img Post Thumbnail as a background of whole post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

anyone help me to make the full background of my wp loop posts is the thumbnail of featured image of the post

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfgN3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `header.php` OR `single.php` file (wherever your opening `<body>` element is) you can do something like:

`<body style="background: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>') no-repeat center center;">`

OR you could wrap your post in a new wrapper `div` and set the background the same way. **Note** You will have to be inside the loop to use the `$post` object properly OR you can call `global $post;` at the top of the file you are trying to set this on.

If you wish to use the **full** version of the uploaded featured image, simply change the `thumbnail` parameter to `full` in the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` function.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Answer (score 0):

You can get featured image url in wp loop by post id and add featured image as background image to your main div

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
  <div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
```

Comment: WP has a function to retrieve the post thumbnail URL now, `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`

Comment: Yes we can also get image url with get_the_post_thumbnail_url()  as well